# What is the Biblical basis for the idea that spiritual gifts are no longer relevant?

Tags: biblical-basis, spiritual-gifts

There is a verse that some denominations use to say that the gifts are not operative since the days of the Apostles. Where is that verse?

Comment: I have updated your title to both match your question, and to be on-topic and less opinion-based. And welcome to our site!

Answer (score 3):

1 Corinthians 13 8 is a [verse](http://biblehub.com/1_corinthians/13-8.htm) sometimes referred to as supporting the theory that some spiritual gifts no longer operate.

> Love never fails: but whether there be prophecies, they shall fail; whether there be tongues, they shall cease; whether there be knowledge, it shall vanish away.

This  [article](http://www.gty.org/resources/distinctives/DD06/the-gift-of-tongues) discusses the question from the perspective of Grace Community Church California, concluding that some gifts no longer operate.

Comment: Good link, the only difficulty in the article is the "absence of evidence /= evidence of absence" issue (in terms of where in Scripture evidentiary issues end) but that should be taken up with the author rather than here.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The verse is 1Corinthians 13:8.

In this article
http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2009334#h=11

produced by Jehovah's Witnesses the cessation of gifts like healing is discussed: the salient points are pretty much contained in the paragraphs below :

> "During the first century, miraculous healings were performed by Jesus Christ and his apostles. At that time in Christian history, the gifts of the spirit, including the ability to perform healings, were for the glory of God and were a sign of Jehovah’s approval and blessing on the young Christian congregation. But once mature or fully established, rather than pointing to special gifts, the Christian congregation would point to its display of unswerving faith, hope, and love as evidence of God’s approval. (John 13:35; 1 Corinthians 13:13) Thus, about the year 100 C.E., miraculous healings as a mark of God’s favor ceased"
>
> Evidently, with the death of the apostles, the transmittal of the gifts ended, and the miraculous gifts of the spirit ceased altogether as those who had received these gifts died.

So it would be wise for Christians to ask:  Is it possible for other spiritual creatures to enable humans to appear to have a gift like healing that would in fact be demonic at its source?

1 Corinthians 11:14&15 (NIV)

> 14 And no wonder, for Satan himself masquerades as an angel of light.
> 15 It is not surprising, then, if his servants also masquerade as servants of righteousness. Their end will be what their actions deserve.